# How many permutations are there if 6 white and 6 black objects are placed around a disk?

Tags: combinatorics

I tried to ask such question on Stack Exchange Puzzling, but they closed it and told me it's a mathematical problem rather than a riddle. Oh well.

Suppose we have 6 identical white balls and 6 identical black balls. They are then placed around something circular, e.g. it may be something like a disk, similar to clock face. The positions/places are not fixed. But we can rotate the disk freely and we can look at it from both sides. This won't change our arrangement of balls.

The question is: how many different permutations can exist, if (essentially) 6 identical objects of one kind and 6 of another kind together form a closed system, but we can rotate it back and forth freely?

I guess if there are 6 boys and 6 girls around a table, then we have 77 different combinations. But in this case, we can't look at them from beneath. In my case, we can look from any side (front or back), and every specific permutation will remain the same.

I hope I explained it well. I have already tried asking it on a different site (outside of Puzzling, i.e. yet another site)—unfortunately no answers, even from mathematicians. The problem is important to me.

Comment: The relevant combinatorics term is [bracelets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)).

Comment: The applicable technique is [Burnside counting lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma).  The Wikipedia article gives some examples of how to use it; also have a couple of examples [on my blog](https://blog.plover.com/math/polya-burnside.html).  Just now I somewhat carelessly computed the answer to be $50$.  For boys and girls around a table, I get $80$.

Comment: Also, Marko Riedel has [an extensive list of posts on this site that involve the counting lemma](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13335/25554), and it includes a whole section on “necklaces and bracelets”; one of those might have what you are looking for.